# how to use GPUImage without scale in android

Tags: android, gpuimage

how to use GPUImage library without resizing original image and I need to apply for a filter like as Pixelate or Blur to an entire GPUImageView.

I thought to use GPUImage but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You change GPUImage library GPUImageRendering class
below code is

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 CyberAgent
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.util.TextureRotationUtil;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import static jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.util.TextureRotationUtil.TEXTURE_NO_ROTATION;

@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
@TargetApi(11)
public class GPUImageRenderer implements Renderer, PreviewCallback {
    public static final int NO_IMAGE = -1;
    static final float CUBE[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    private GPUImageFilter mFilter;

    public final Object mSurfaceChangedWaiter = new Object();

    private int mGLTextureId = NO_IMAGE;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture = null;
    private final FloatBuffer mGLCubeBuffer;
    private final FloatBuffer mGLTextureBuffer;
    private IntBuffer mGLRgbBuffer;
    int mwidth,mheight,wheight;
    private int mOutputWidth;
    private int mOutputHeight;
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private int mAddedPadding;

    private final Queue<Runnable> mRunOnDraw;
    private final Queue<Runnable> mRunOnDrawEnd;
    private Rotation mRotation;
    private boolean mFlipHorizontal;
    private boolean mFlipVertical;
    private GPUImage.ScaleType mScaleType = GPUImage.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    public GPUImageRenderer(final GPUImageFilter filter) {
        mFilter = filter;
        mRunOnDraw = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
        mRunOnDrawEnd = new LinkedList<Runnable>();

        mGLCubeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(CUBE.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        mGLCubeBuffer.put(CUBE).position(0);

        mGLTextureBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(TEXTURE_NO_ROTATION.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        setRotation(Rotation.NORMAL, false, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(final GL10 unused, final EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        mFilter.init();
    }

    public void onSurfacSize(final int width, final int height) {
        mwidth=width;
        mheight=height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(final GL10 gl, final int width, final int height) {

        if(height>mheight)
        {
            mOutputWidth = mwidth;
            mOutputHeight = mheight;
            GLES20.glViewport(0,0, mwidth, mheight);
            //  GLES20.glViewport(0+(mwidth/2), 0+(mheight/2), mwidth, mheight);
            mFilter.onOutputSizeChanged(mwidth,mheight);
        }
        else
        {
            mOutputWidth = width;
            mOutputHeight = height;
            GLES20.glViewport(0,0, width, height);
            mFilter.onOutputSizeChanged(width,height);
        }
        // GLES20.glViewport(20,-20, width, height);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mFilter.getProgram());
        adjustImageScaling();
        synchronized (mSurfaceChangedWaiter) {
            mSurfaceChangedWaiter.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        runAll(mRunOnDraw);
        mFilter.onDraw(mGLTextureId, mGLCubeBuffer, mGLTextureBuffer);
        runAll(mRunOnDrawEnd);
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null) {
            mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        }
    }

    private void runAll(Queue<Runnable> queue) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                queue.poll().run();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
        final Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        if (mGLRgbBuffer == null) {
            mGLRgbBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(previewSize.width * previewSize.height);
        }
        if (mRunOnDraw.isEmpty()) {
            runOnDraw(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    GPUImageNativeLibrary.YUVtoRBGA(data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height,
                            mGLRgbBuffer.array());
                    mGLTextureId = OpenGlUtils.loadTexture(mGLRgbBuffer, previewSize, mGLTextureId);
                    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);

                    if (mImageWidth != previewSize.width) {
                        mImageWidth = previewSize.width;
                        mImageHeight = previewSize.height;
                        adjustImageScaling();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setUpSurfaceTexture(final Camera camera) {
        runOnDraw(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] textures = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
                mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textures[0]);
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                    camera.setPreviewCallback(GPUImageRenderer.this);
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFilter(final GPUImageFilter filter) {
        runOnDraw(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final GPUImageFilter oldFilter = mFilter;
                mFilter = filter;
                if (oldFilter != null) {
                    oldFilter.destroy();
                }
                mFilter.init();
                GLES20.glUseProgram(mFilter.getProgram());
                mFilter.onOutputSizeChanged(mOutputWidth, mOutputHeight);
            }
        });
    }
    public void setFilter3(final GPUImageFilter filter) {
        runOnDraw(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final GPUImageFilter oldFilter = mFilter;
                mFilter = filter;
//                if (oldFilter != null) {
//                    oldFilter.destroy();
//                }
                mFilter.init();
                GLES20.glUseProgram(mFilter.getProgram());
                mFilter.onOutputSizeChanged(mOutputWidth, mOutputHeight);
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteImage() {
        runOnDraw(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, new int[]{
                        mGLTextureId
                }, 0);
                mGLTextureId = NO_IMAGE;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap) {
        setImageBitmap(bitmap, true);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap, final boolean recycle) {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        runOnDraw(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
                if (bitmap.getWidth() % 2 == 1) {
                    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth() + 1, bitmap.getHeight(),
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas can = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);
                    can.drawARGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
                    can.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    mAddedPadding = 1;
                } else {
                    mAddedPadding = 0;
                }

                mGLTextureId = OpenGlUtils.loadTexture(
                        resizedBitmap != null ? resizedBitmap : bitmap, mGLTextureId, recycle);
                if (resizedBitmap != null) {
                    resizedBitmap.recycle();
                }
                mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                adjustImageScaling();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setScaleType(GPUImage.ScaleType scaleType) {
        mScaleType = scaleType;
    }

    protected int getFrameWidth() {
        return mOutputWidth;
    }

    protected int getFrameHeight() {
        return mOutputHeight;
    }

    private void adjustImageScaling() {
        float outputWidth = mOutputWidth;
        float outputHeight = mOutputHeight;
        if (mRotation == Rotation.ROTATION_270 || mRotation == Rotation.ROTATION_90) {
            outputWidth = mOutputHeight;
            outputHeight = mOutputWidth;
        }

        float ratio1 = outputWidth / mImageWidth;
        float ratio2 =outputHeight / mImageHeight;
        float ratioMax = Math.max(ratio1, ratio2);
        int imageWidthNew = (Math.round(mImageWidth * ratioMax));
        int imageHeightNew = (Math.round(mImageHeight * ratioMax));

        float ratioWidth = imageWidthNew / (outputWidth);
        float ratioHeight = imageHeightNew / (outputHeight);

        float[] cube = CUBE;
        float[] textureCords = TextureRotationUtil.getRotation(mRotation, mFlipHorizontal, mFlipVertical);
        if (mScaleType == GPUImage.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) {
            float distHorizontal = (1 - 1 / ratioWidth) / 2;
            float distVertical = (1 - 1 / ratioHeight) / 2;
            textureCords = new float[]{
                    addDistance(textureCords[0], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[1], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[2], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[3], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[4], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[5], distVertical),
                    addDistance(textureCords[6], distHorizontal), addDistance(textureCords[7], distVertical),
            };
        } else {
            cube = new float[]{
                    CUBE[0] * ratioWidth, CUBE[1] * ratioHeight,
                    CUBE[2] * ratioWidth, CUBE[3] * ratioHeight,
                    CUBE[4] * ratioWidth, CUBE[5] * ratioHeight,
                    CUBE[6] * ratioWidth, CUBE[7] * ratioHeight,
            };
        }

        mGLCubeBuffer.clear();
        mGLCubeBuffer.put(cube).position(0);
        mGLTextureBuffer.clear();
        mGLTextureBuffer.put(textureCords).position(0);
    }


    private float addDistance(float coordinate, float distance) {
        return coordinate == 0.0f ? distance : 1 - distance;
    }

    public void setRotationCamera(final Rotation rotation, final boolean flipHorizontal,
            final boolean flipVertical) {
        setRotation(rotation, flipVertical, flipHorizontal);
    }

    public void setRotation(final Rotation rotation, final boolean flipHorizontal,
            final boolean flipVertical) {
        mRotation = rotation;
        mFlipHorizontal = flipHorizontal;
        mFlipVertical = flipVertical;
        adjustImageScaling();
    }

    public Rotation getRotation() {
        return mRotation;
    }

    public boolean isFlippedHorizontally() {
        return mFlipHorizontal;
    }

    public boolean isFlippedVertically() {
        return mFlipVertical;
    }

    protected void runOnDraw(final Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (mRunOnDraw) {
            mRunOnDraw.add(runnable);
        }
    }

    protected void runOnDrawEnd(final Runnable runnable) {
        synchronized (mRunOnDrawEnd) {
            mRunOnDrawEnd.add(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ram, i have changed code which you given but there is a blank screen is coming there is no result, can you help me please !

Comment: what did you have change in the GPUImageRendering class? Could you explain it.