# GPUImage library for Android - Load and save pic with full size

Tags: android, image, gpuimage

I connected GPUImage library for android, everything works pretty nice, but when i try to load image it crops and size is very small, how can i load and save pic in full size?

Comment: Nobody is even going to be able to guess the problem if you don't give us some context. How about you post some relevant code?

Comment: Ok, here is a library itself [GPUImage](http://https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/). Here is my project(zip) - [Project]http://rghost.ru/private/54410484/bc2932052ae211df4d63525188be1fbb/)

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant post your code. Show us what you tried so far and show us where exactly in that code you encounter problems.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller, here is my [PROJECT](http://rghost.ru/private/54410484/bc2932052ae211df4d63525188be1fbb/).

Comment: I tried to solve my problem and i found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974533/how-to-use-gpuimage-without-scale-in-android/). But i still can't load full-size image, i can set sizes which are must  be not more than my phone's screen

Comment: You know that in Gallery app you see full-size image, i have to make like in Gallery app

Comment: I'm not gonna download your project and look through the source code. Post the relevant bits of code, like the ones where you actually load the images. Nobody is just going to solve your problems for you. Show some of your own effort. How about you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you come back here and ask a question.

Comment: Oh and this will help too: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller, ok, here is my class where i load image - [Class](http://rghost.ru/download/private/54411378/95368b2e70d4b912467f710cb558c293/81533467ab8812f6223afc7e5008ecb866dd42e4/GPUImageRenderer.java/).

Comment: You realise you can post code in your question? I don't even click on your links.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller, so many characters, i can't post my code here

Comment: Have you look at other questions? Edit it in your question.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller, so, i thought you know GPUImage library and you know how to solve my problem, sorry.

Comment: @JHS, i have the same problem for load full image in to GPUImageView. I find the solution for last few month but not yet get the solution. If you have find any solution please share to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for save photo wit full resolution using GPUImage :

```
private void startSavePhoto(String originalPhotoFilePath) {
        final String TEMP_FOLDER = AppConst.PATH_FILE_SAVE_PHOTO + AppConst.PATH_FILE_SAVE_TEMP;
        ExtraUtils.createFolder(TEMP_FOLDER);
        final String TEMP_FILE_NAME = ".ImageEffect.png";

        // Save Photo based on original file
        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalPhotoFilePath);
        String pathFile = TEMP_FOLDER + File.separator + TEMP_FILE_NAME;
        Bitmap bitmap = gpuImage.getGPUImage().getBitmapWithFilterApplied(source);

        // Bitmap to File
        if (ExtraUtils.saveBitmapToPNG(bitmap, pathFile)) {
            showSaveWithAdsDialog(pathFile);
        } else {
            T.show(R.string.error_save_image);
        }
    }
```